# Get share link of multiple files in Google Drive to put in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, hyperlink, google-drive-api

I have this script which creates shareable links from files inside the folder, and then puts the links into a spreadsheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var c=s.getActiveCell();
  var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById("REPLACE_[ID]_HERE");
  var files=fldr.getFiles();
  var names=[],f,str;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f=files.next();
    str='=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '","' + f.getName() + '")';
    names.push([str]);
  }
  s.getRange(c.getRow(),c.getColumn(),names.length).setFormulas(names);
}
```

Instead I get this error

```
The number of rows in the range must be at least 1. (line 13, file "Code")
```

Script was based off this answer
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/119646

Comment: If the error line is `s.getRange(c.getRow(),c.getColumn(),names.length).setFormulas(names)`, I think that the reason of `The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.` is due to that the length of `names` is `0`. So how about confirming the value of `names` by putting `Logger.log(names.length)` after the while loop?

Comment: I've added Logger.log(names.length), I receive this result [19-09-09 12:02:28:887 PDT] 0.0

Comment: Thank you for replying. The reason of your issue is that `names.length` is `0`. This means that there are no files in the folder of `"REPLACE_[ID]_HERE"`. So could please confirm it?

Comment: I confirm there are no files just folders. I think I found the issue. instead of var files=fldr.getFiles(); it should be var files = fldr.getFolders()

Comment: Answer posted. I will accept it tomorrow, as allowed by Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my file directory, there are only folders.

So to get links of shareable folders, you will need to use the getFolders() method.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var c=s.getActiveCell();
  var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById("REPLACE_[ID]_HERE");
  var files=fldr.getFolders();
  var names=[],f,str;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f=files.next();
    str='=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '","' + f.getName() + '")';
    names.push([str]);
  }
  s.getRange(c.getRow(),c.getColumn(),names.length).setFormulas(names);
}
```